# Problem While trying to create React Roles System

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a reaction role system and I'm very confused, because I can't find a way to give a role to the user when they trigger a MessageReaction.
I have made an embed that is supposed to give a role to the user based on the command it gets triggered through.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  let role = message.mentions.roles.first()
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
  embed.setTitle("Reaction Role");
  embed.setColor("BLUE");
  embed.setDescription("Tap the Reaction to get role" + role);
  if (message.content === `${prefix}reactionrole ${role}`)(message.channel.send(embed)).then(messageReaction => {
    messageReaction.react("✅")
  })
})
```

But I somehow want to give the role to any user who replies to this specific message with the given reaction.
I'm here to answer your questions, if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ReactionCollector to do your request. Find tutorials [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html).

An example for your code can be:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  let role = message.mentions.roles.first()
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
  embed.setTitle("Reaction Role");
  embed.setColor("BLUE");
  embed.setDescription("Tap the Reaction to get role" + role);
  if (message.content === `${prefix}reactionrole ${role}`)(message.channel.send(embed)).then(messageReaction => {
    messageReaction.react("✅")
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return reaction.emoji.name === '✅';
    };

    const collector = messageReaction.createReactionCollector(filter);

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
      message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(role.id);
    });
  })
})
```

You can also find other options such as json/sqlite/sql storage to store the message id and the role id. And then use the [MessageReactionAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event to trigger the system and add the role.

Comment: The code should be working fine, although it doesn't

Comment: Now it crashes saying cannot read property get of undefined, right here`message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(role.id);`

Comment: Are you using discord.js v12 ?

Comment: Is there a problem with that?

Comment: The code is working on my side with discord.js v12. Are you using the command in a guild?

Comment: Yes I am using the command and testing it in a guild